# Calling Youtube API for user Channels returns authorizationRequired

Tags: php, api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

I am trying to call Youtube API for user Channels:

https://content-youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&part=statistics&mine=true&key=AIXXXXX

It returns the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "The request uses the \u003ccode\u003emine\u003c/code\u003e parameter but is not properly authorized.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request uses the \u003ccode\u003emine\u003c/code\u003e parameter but is not properly authorized.",
        "domain": "youtube.parameter",
        "reason": "authorizationRequired",
        "location": "mine",
        "locationType": "parameter"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I haven't been able to find a proper answer on stackoverflow or on youtube documentation to overcome this issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For certain requests you need user authorisation. Here is the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/php#step_3_run_an_authorized_request) for PHP

Comment: @bluecouch I have seen the documentation. How do you set the authorisation?

Comment: I believe OAuth 2.0 [(docs)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps) is used.  This [library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) may also help you

Answer (score 0):

if you check the documentation for [channels.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) you will fine that it states

[image]

You need to be authorized by the user with that scope and send the access token as an authorization header bearer token.

I cant see how you are using php as you have not posted a full example of what you are doing.

As you can see this request requires an authorization header.   With a valid access token.  Your not sending one.

```
curl \
  'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

## php example

From [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?apix=true)

```
<?php

/**
 * Sample PHP code for youtube.channels.list
 * See instructions for running these code samples locally:
 * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/code-samples#php
 */

if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
  throw new Exception(sprintf('Please run "composer require google/apiclient:~2.0" in "%s"', __DIR__));
}
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('API code samples');
$client->setScopes([
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
]);

// TODO: For this request to work, you must replace
//       "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FILE.json" with a pointer to your
//       client_secret.json file. For more information, see
//       https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys
$client->setAuthConfig('YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FILE.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');

// Request authorization from the user.
$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
printf("Open this link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
print('Enter verification code: ');
$authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

// Exchange authorization code for an access token.
$accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

// Define service object for making API requests.
$service = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

$response = $service->channels->listChannels('');
print_r($response);
```

Comment: I have added ./auth/youtubepartner-channel-audit and ../auth/youtube.readonly scopes and submitted for review. Do you think this will fix the issue once it is approved?

Comment: Definitely not this is something in your code. Your not authorizing your request properly.